# How use php to manipulate files inside zip files?

Tags: php, zip

If I have some text files inside zip files, is it possible to manipulate this text files and change information inside this zip file?

For example, if I have the file `test.txt` inside `test.zip`, is it possible to open this text file and change the content and put other, the same as if I use `fopen`, `fputs` and `fclose` but all inside the zip?

Comment: Take a look at the functions available in the [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class

Comment: [`PharData`](http://php.net/PharData) is often the simpler alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! :)

Like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('test.zip');

// Read from file
$contents = $zip->getFromName('test.txt');
var_dump($contents);

// Write to file
$zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'foo bar');

// Close (and re-pack) zip file. Don't miss that!
$zip->close();
```

Check the documentation of the [`ZipArchive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class.